# How can I simplify this if else statement to reduce code repetition?

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, logic, simplify

How can i simplify this if else statement to reduce code repetition?
As you can see, the variable uri is assigned with just 1 parameter changing.

```
    var uri: String?

    if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        uri = StickerFileManager.checkIfStickerCreated(
            sticker,
            head,
            sticker.translatedOTFText
        )
        if (uri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ResourceDownloadManager.downloadResource(sticker)
            uri = StickerCreator().createStickerWith(
                sticker,
                head,
                sticker.translatedOTFText
            )
        }
    } else {
        uri = StickerFileManager.checkIfStickerCreated(
            sticker,
            head,
            otfText
        )
        if (uri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ResourceDownloadManager.downloadResource(sticker)
            uri = StickerCreator().createStickerWith(
                sticker,
                head,
                otfText
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. If it is simply null than you should use `otfText ?: sticker.translatedOTFText` If it is nullOrEmpty then below method can be used

```
     uri = StickerFileManager.checkIfStickerCreated(
          sticker,
          head,
          if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) sticker.translatedOTFText else otfText)
            if (uri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                ResourceDownloadManager.downloadResource(sticker)
                uri = StickerCreator().createStickerWith(
                    sticker,
                    head,
                    if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) sticker.translatedOTFText else otfText
                )
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
var text = if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) sticker.translatedOTFText else otfText
var uri = StickerFileManager.checkIfStickerCreated(
    sticker,
    head,
    text
)
if (uri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    ResourceDownloadManager.downloadResource(sticker)
    uri = StickerCreator().createStickerWith(
        sticker,
        head,
        text
    )
}
```

It's very similar to [Shahnawaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70435070/1514861) but I think it's better to avoid having to do the same check twice so I save the result in the `text` variable and use that one instead at the two spots.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var uri = StickerFileManager.checkIfStickerCreated(
    sticker,
    head,
    if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) sticker.translatedOTFText else otfText
)


if (uri.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    ResourceDownloadManager.downloadResource(sticker)
    uri = StickerCreator().createStickerWith(
        sticker,
        head,
         if (otfText.isNullOrEmpty()) sticker.translatedOTFText else otfText
    )
}
```